# Python Read Arduino Serial Only Once

Tags: python-2.7, arduino, pyserial

I'm tring to read when the value on A0 in my Arduino changes. The code in the Arduino seems to be OK since when I use the serial monitor the value changes as expected. However, when I run my Python code, it only reads the initial value of the Arduino. If the value changes, it still displays the initial value. Below is my Python code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
import sys
import serial
import time
import datetime
import ast

#--- open up the serial port to get data transmitted to arduino
ser = serial.Serial('COM3', \
                    baudrate = 9600, timeout = 1)


#main
while True :
    ser.readline()
    #--- Read in the data and split the line into words
    data = ser.readline()
    timestamp = datetime.datetime.now()
    hora = timestamp.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

    #--- If at least nine fields exists then parse the data
    if (ast.literal_eval(data) > 800) :
        time.sleep(1)   
        print "Alarme!!!, %s" % ast.literal_eval(data)
        time.sleep(150)
        ser.readline()
    else :
        print "ok, %s" % (data)
        time.sleep(1)
        ser.readline()
```

Comment: Is it printing 'Alarme'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding, ser.flush() ser.flushInput() ser.flushOutput() to the end of the loop.
 To flush the input and output buffer.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop is throwing away many lines.  It goes [discard, read, discard], repeat.   Is that intentional?

Comment: No I did this to try  read new data but it still on reads the value once, I believe my problem has something to do with the arduino sending the same info many times and is creating a buffer so big that for the time I run my code I'm only reading that buffer, I'll try to add a delay to the arduino so it will only send the info 1 every seconf